# Flutter Chips clickable avatar not working

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a dynamic list of raw chips inside GridView builder, and I want when the user clicks on the avatar icon to remove the item from the list but clicking function never been called.

I tried to wrap the Avatar icon with InkWell or GestureDetector and use onTap function I debugged the code and tried some breakpoint inside onTap but it's never called, and there is no clicking sound, even called the chipBuilder function from outside the GrideView but it' still not onTap() never called.

GridView widget

```dart
 GridView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: storingDataList.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    childAspectRatio: 3,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => chipBuilder(
                    label: storingDataList[index],
                    onAvatarTap: () {
                      Toaster.create("Item removed", context);
                      setState(() {
                       storingDataList.removeAt(index);
                     });       
             }));
```

Chip builder function:

```dart
 Widget chipBuilder({String label, VoidCallback onAvatarTap}) => RawChip(
        avatar: InkWell(
          onTap: onAvatarTap,
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colours.colorTextPrimary,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
              child:  Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colours.colorPrimary,
                ),
              ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colours.colorPrimary,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        label: Text(label,
            style: CustomTextStyles.textSecondary.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
        labelStyle: CustomTextStyles.textSecondary.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colours.colorPrimary, width: 0)),
      );
```

And I don't any error message.

The current output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [KlausJokinen](https://github.com/KlausJokinen) for pointing me to the problem in this [issue 39045](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39045#issuecomment-523892469).

> Reason for this behavior is that RawChip is consuming the tap event. Why not use use
> onPressed: from RawChip

If SelectableChipAttributes.onSelected, TappableChipAttributes.onPressed, and DeletableChipAttributes.onDelete are null then RawChip acts like it's disabled.

> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawChip/isEnabled.html

I have removed InkWell from `avatar:` and I put my icon inside `deleteIcon:` instead of `avatar:` and I used `onDeleted:` function to call onAvatarTap, and it worked.

```dart
  Widget chipBuilder({String label, VoidCallback onAvatarTap}) => RawChip(
       onDeleted: onAvatarTap,
       deleteIcon:  Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colours.colorTextPrimary,
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
         child: Icon(
           Icons.close,
           color: Colours.colorPrimary,
         ),
       ),
        backgroundColor: Colours.colorPrimary,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        label: Text(label,
            style:
                CustomTextStyles.textSecondary.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
        labelStyle:
            CustomTextStyles.textSecondary.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colours.colorPrimary, width: 0)),
      );
```